# Deploy Django project on heroku (python 3.4.3)

Tags: python, django, heroku

Im folowing [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) guide step by step. Except im using **python 3.4.3** and **pyvenv** instead of **virtualenv**. I have installed:

- Python 3.4.3
- Django 1.8.2
- python-psycopg2
- libpq-dev

My steps are:

1. mkdir hellodjango && cd hellodjango
2. pyvenv venv
3. source venv/bin/activate
4. pip install django-toolbelt (success)
5. django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
6. created Procfile (web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -)
7. foreman start (success and check working app in browser)
8. pip freeze > requirements.txt
9. **add runtime.txt (python-3.4.3)**
10. filled **settings.py** and **wsgi.py** as guide says
11. Init and commit git repo
12. heroku create (success)
13. git push heroku master (error!)

So **git push heroku master** says that:

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 2.90 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing runtime ( 
remote: python-3.4.3)
remote:  !     Requested runtime ( 
remote: python-3.4.3) is not available for this stack (cedar-14).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to cryptic-thicket-7510.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/cryptic-thicket-7510.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/cryptic-thicket-7510.git'
```

As you can see main error is `Requested runtime (remote: python-3.4.3) is not available for this stack (cedar-14).` What am i doing wrong?

Comment: change in runtime.txt to **python-3.4.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) heroku does support python 3.4.3. You just need to use appropriate **pip** version. So [**pip3** install django-toolbelt] instead of [**pip** install django-toolbelt]

Comment: The version you use to install the toolbelt locally has nothing to do with what runs on the server.

Comment: I know, but it worked. Don't know why, maybe someone will explain. Is it possible that different versions of **pip** generates different requirements.txt?